# Why MVC Sweet Alert will Auto Close?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert, auto-close

Below are my coding. Please advise why the sweet alert only pop up not up to 1 second then auto Redirect to another page.

From HTML:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/ABC/AddST/",
  data: {
    "username": $("#username").val(),
    "fullname": $("#fullname").val()
  },
  type: "POST"
}).success(function(data) {
  swal({
    title: "Done!",
    text: "Sales Team was successfully added!",
    type: "success"
  }, function() {
    window.location.href = '/ABC/STList';
  });
}).error(function(data) {
  swal("Oops", "We couldn't connect to the server!", "error");
});
```

From Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSalesTeam(string username, string fullname)
{
    var st = new Sales();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        st.Username = username;
        st.FullName = fullname;
        db.User.Add(st);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("SalesTeamList");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it a timer.

```
swal({
  title: "Done!",
  text: "Sales Team was successfully added!",
  type: "success",
  timer: 1000, // Wait 1 second
  showConfirmButton: false // No reason to show the button
}, function() {
  window.location.href = '/ABC/STList';
});
```

Comment: Why showConfirmButton should be false? I tried to put in timer but no showConfirmButton, it return the same result for me. But if i put in both, it can work

Comment: @Yuan [It works either way.](https://jsfiddle.net/r6ucewha/) It just doesn't make much sense to have a confirmation button when the page is being redirected.

Comment: How about I need the confirm button?

Comment: @Yuan If you need it, then don't set `showConfirmButton` to `false` just like I show in the code I linked to. It's that easy.

Comment: @Yuan Is this code not working for you? Because I guarantee it does what you've asked.

Comment: I set timer: 5000, it appeared only up to 2 seconds

Comment: @Yuan Then you're closing it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from the question, you want to show the alert, and then when the user click in the *confirm* button, then redirect to the `/ABC/STList` page, (instead of redirecting the user automatically), right? If so. have you tried with this?:

```
swal({
  title: "Done!",
  text: "Sales Team was successfully added!",
  type: "success",
  showCancelButton: false,
  confirmButtonText: "Ok",   
  closeOnConfirm: false
}, function() {
  window.location.href = '/ABC/STList';
});
```

========================

EDIT: If you want, you can remove the `closeOnConfirm: false` line and the popup will be closed after clicking the *ok* button (but you will be still redirected). Is just because is better for the End User to see that the popup is closed after clicking the button.

Comment: ya, you get what I mean. but I tried your code, the result still the same

Comment: Please try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r6ucewha/2/). It will redirect you just if you click in the _ok_ button.

Answer (score 0):

Adding e.preventDefault() before and after $ajax function will do.

```
e.preventDefault();  
$.ajax({
  url: "/ABC/AddST/",
  data: {
    "username": $("#username").val(),
    "fullname": $("#fullname").val()
  },
  type: "POST"
}).success(function(data) {
  swal({
    title: "Done!",
    text: "Sales Team was successfully added!",
    type: "success"
  }, function() {
    window.location.href = '/ABC/STList';
  });
}).error(function(data) {
  swal("Oops", "We couldn't connect to the server!", "error");
});
e.preventDefault();
```